# Multiple input in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Doctor table which store doctor information like:

```
Doctor_ID  Name   Address
 1         Andy   123 New York
 2         Mark   123 New York
 3         Roshan 123 New York
```

I have created a Temp table which has following data:

```
Name  Address
Mark  123 New York
Andy   123 New York
```

Now I need query which will provide Doctor IDs for data present in temp table.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Fastest way to learn SQL is to write some, without using SO first.

Comment: Select * from doctor as d,temp as t where d.name=t.name and d.address=t.address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your Doctors table and your Temp table.

```
select a.doctor_id , b.name , b,address
from Doctors a join Temp_table b 
on a.name = b.name 
and a.address = b.address;
```

Your name + address column must be unique otherwise, you will get multiple doctor id's with same name and address.